# 'Approvals Classic' does not appear in the Email Studio drop down

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

We are currently encountering an issue where the 'Approvals Classic' tab is not appearing whenever we hover over the Email Studio (wherein the approvals classic tab should be in the drop down of the email studio) .

We have already checked the roles and it appears all Approvals are allowed on the roles.

Apparently 2 users has the same roles. 1 can see the Approvals Classic on the drop down and the other can't .

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With the January 2020 release, Marketing Cloud retires Approval Classic, Campaigns Approvals, and Classic Live Content.

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_content_and_email_creation_tools.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null